# deduct insured amount after every routine checkup for each employee

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is the sample data for my problem,

```
List<EMPINSURED> lstEmpIns = new List<EMPINSURED>{
    new EMPINSURED{ EmpID = 558, TOTAL_INSURED_AMT = 50000},
    new EMPINSURED{ EmpID = 559, TOTAL_INSURED_AMT = 75000} 
};

List<EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY> lstEmpRoutineChkHist = new List<EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY>{
    new EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY{ ID = 1, EmpID = 558, ROUTINE_CHECKUP = 1, CHECK_UP_CHARGE = 20000},
    new EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY{ ID = 2, EmpID = 559, ROUTINE_CHECKUP = 1, CHECK_UP_CHARGE = 35000},
    new EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY{ ID = 3, EmpID = 558, ROUTINE_CHECKUP = 2, CHECK_UP_CHARGE = 10000},
    new EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY{ ID = 4, EmpID = 559, ROUTINE_CHECKUP = 2, CHECK_UP_CHARGE = 10000},
    new EMP_ROUTINE_CHECKUP_HISTORY{ ID = 5, EmpID = 558, ROUTINE_CHECKUP = 3, CHECK_UP_CHARGE = 20000}
};
```

In a year, an Employee is allowed only three routine checkups. When an employee goes for routine checkup, his/her check up charges must be deducted from the total insured amount. For the next routine check up, employee will be awarded check up charges only for the remaining amount he/she has from the total insured amount, any expenses more than that, the company will not bear.
So for the logic for calculating `REMAINING AMOUNT` would be somewhat like this ::

```
    int var = 0;
if(ROUTINE_CHECKUP == 1)
{
    REMAINING_AMOUNT = TOTAL_INSURED_AMT - CHECK_UP_CHARGE;
    var = CHECK_UP_CHARGE;
} 
else if (ROUTINE_CHECKUP == 2)
{
    REMAINING_AMOUNT = TOTAL_INSURED_AMT - (CHECK_UP_CHARGE + var);
    var = CHECK_UP_CHARGE + var;
}
else if (ROUTINE_CHECKUP == 3)
{
    REMAINING_AMOUNT = TOTAL_INSURED_AMT - (CHECK_UP_CHARGE + var);
    var = CHECK_UP_CHARGE + var;
}
```

How to develop the LINQ query to get the below report data using this logic or there may some better way to do this.
Please see the attached image for report format.

[image]

Comment: What about Employees that didn't have a Checkup yet? Do you want them also in the list, with `RoutineChekup = 0, CheckupCharge=0, RemainingAmount = TotalInsuredAmount`?

Comment: Yes, I have to show them also.

Answer (score 2):

Using some `System.Linq` extension methods, you can `Join` the `lstEmpIns` list with the `lstEmpRoutineChkHist` list on the `EmpId` field into an anonymous type that has the values for the columns from the appropriate fields in each list, and order the results by `RoutineCheckup` using `OrderBy`.

The ugly part is determining the `RemainingBalance`, because we have to lookup all the records for that employee where the `RoutineCheckup` is less than or equal to the current item, and then sum the `CheckupCharge` so we can deduct it from `RemainingBalance`. There's probably a better way to do it, but this is what I came up with.

Here's a sample based on your code but using modern naming conventions:

```
var results = empInsureds
    .Join(empRoutineCheckupHistories,
        emp => emp.EmpId,
        hist => hist.EmpId,
        (emp, hist) => new
        {
            emp.EmpId,
            emp.TotalInsuredAmt,
            hist.RoutineCheckup,
            hist.CheckupCharge,
            RemainingBalance =
                emp.TotalInsuredAmt -
                empRoutineCheckupHistories
                    .Where(h => h.EmpId == hist.EmpId &&
                                h.RoutineCheckup <= hist.RoutineCheckup)
                    .Sum(h => h.CheckupCharge)
        })
    .OrderBy(r => r.RoutineCheckup)
    .ToList();
```

Some code to generate the output:

```
Console.WindowWidth = 81;

Console.WriteLine(GetRow("EmpID", "Total Insured Amt", "Routine Checkup", 
    "Checkup Charge", "Remaining Amount"));

Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));

results.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(GetRow($"{r.EmpId}", $"{r.TotalInsuredAmt:C}", 
    $"{r.RoutineCheckup}", $"{r.CheckupCharge:C}", $"{r.RemainingBalance:C}")));

GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
```

Which uses the helper function:

```
public static string GetRow(string col1, string col2, string col3, string col4, 
    string col5)
{
    return col1.PadRight(5) + " | " +
           col2.PadLeft(17) + " | " +
           col3.PadRight(16) + " | " +
           col4.PadLeft(14) + " | " +
           col5.PadLeft(16);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Can I use `group` clause with this for group by `EmpID, RoutineCheckup`?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netcore-3.1), or its IEnumerable equivalent if your sources are not IQueryable, but IEnumerable.

With a GroupJoin you can get "All Employees, each with all his zero or more Routine Check Ups". By using parameter resultSelector, you can create the desired output.

The advantage of a GroupJoin is that you will also get the Employees that have had no Checkups until now. If you would use a Join, then you wouldn't get these Employees at all.

```
var employeesWithTheirCheckups = dbContext.Employees.GroupJoin(
    dbContext.RoutineCheckUps,

    employee => employee.EmpId,     // from every Employee take the primary key
    checkup => checkup.EmpId,       // from every RoutineCheckup take the foreign key
                                   // to the Employee

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Employee and his zero or more Checkups,
    // make one new object:
    (employee, checkupsOfThisEmployee) => new
    {
        EmpId = employee.Id,
        TotalInsuredAmount = employee.TotalInsuredAmount,

        Checkups = checkupsOfThisEmployee.Select(checkup => new
        {
            RoutineCheckup = checkup.RoutineCheckup,
            CheckupCharge = checkup.CheckupCharge,

            // TODO: Remaining Amount   
        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

The Remaining Checkup Charges, equal the total amount of this employee minus this "total checkup charges of this employee until this checkup".

So for the History with RoutineCheckup 2, you need to add up all Charged Amounts of all Histories with RoutineCheckups <= 2.

This is calculated as follows:

```
var chargedUntilNow = checkupsOfThisEmployee
    .Where(checkupOfThisEmployee => checkupOfThisEmployee <= checkup)
    .Select(checkupOfThisEmployee => checkupOfThisEmployee.CheckUpCharge)
    .Sum();
```

The remaining is the total of this employee - chargedUntilNow.

Back to the GroupJoin:

```
(employee, checkupsOfThisEmployee) => new
{
    EmpId = employee.Id,
    TotalInsuredAmount = employee.TotalInsuredAmount,

    Checkups = checkupsOfThisEmployee.Select(checkup => new
    {
        RoutineCheckup = checkup.RoutineCheckup,
        CheckupCharge = checkup.CheckupCharge,

        // remaining is the total of this employee - chargedUntilNow.
        RemainingAmount = employee.TotalInsured -
            checkupsOfThisEmployee
            .Where(checkupOfThisEmployee => checkupOfThisEmployee <= checkup)
            .Select(checkupOfThisEmployee => checkupOfThisEmployee.CheckUpCharge)
            .Sum();
    })
    .ToList(),
```

The result is a sequence of all Employees (well, only his Id, and his total insured amount), each Employee with his zero or more Checkups. Every Checkup will have the RoutineCheckup number, the CheckupAmount, and the RemainingAmount.

Nice thing: you will also have the Employees that didn't have a Checkup yet!

Besides: [EmpId, TotalInsuredAmount], will only be transferred once per Employee. If you would have used a standard Join, then the same [EmpId, TotalInsuredAmount] would have be sent once per Checkup.

If you want it flattened, like your end-result, use SelectMany. Continuing the LINQ:

```
.SelectMany(groupJoinResult, groupJoinResult.Checkups, 

// parameter resultSelector: take the GroupJoinResult, and each one of its Checkups
// to make one new:
(groupJoinResult, checkupOfThisGroupJoinResult) => new
{
    EmpId = groupJoinResult.EmpId,
    TotalInsuredAmount = groupJoinResult.TotalInsuredAmount,

    RoutineCheckUp = checkupOfThisGroupJoinResult.RoutineCheckup,
    CheckupCharge = checkupOfThisGroupJoinResult.CheckupCharge,
    RemainingAmount = checkupOfThisGroupJoinResult.RemainingAmount,
});
```

The problem is that you will loose the Employee that didn't have any Checkups yet. To solve this you'll have to provide a default